# Is this just being picky or is this exploiting the system?

Tags: discussion, edits

Not trying to call this guy out, I'm just curious as to whether or not there is some ulterior motive.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/86860/nate?tab=activity

I know that users can gain rep from making edits, and that this rep is capped at 1,000. If you look at the activity of this user, he makes a large number of edits in a matter of minutes, and nearly every single one of those edits are removing the word "thanks" at the end of a user's post. So is he just being anal because he has some terrible hatred of the word, or is he actually gaining rep for every edit he makes?

Comment: His rep is > 2000, so he isn't gaining reputation. (Not saying this is 100% ok though)

Comment: He's also removing "Hi" at the beginning of a lot of those posts, which makes this totally okay.

Comment: GO NATE GO!!!!!

Comment: He has probably realised that he's close to a copy editor badge and decided to push himself over the edge...

Comment: I would appreciate if he filled out the Edit Summary `:-)`

Comment: He changes correct spelling into incorrect one: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6037557/revisions

Answer (score 15):

Neither.

We have a rule in the FAQ, based from a [Meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), which states:

> ### Can I use a signature or tagline?
>
> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

This discredits it being pickiness of the user, and is actually just enforcing normal site policy that is opposed to decorating your posts with "hi" and "thanks".

The user also has over 2000 reputation. Once you have over 2000 reputation, you no longer can suggest question and answer edits, which means you cannot earn reputation for each one. As such, it is not gaming the system, either.

Comment: Yeah, but systematically searching contributions with "thanks" in them isn't great IMO.

Comment: @Pekka People are using Data Explorer to find *all* sorts of problem kinds of posts to help remove them. I don't find this behavior different from any of that. That said, in those same things, we do always suggest users only target posts like that when they can also do other revisions. Not following that can be problematic, but in the end, it's still enforcing a policy that we're, well, trying to enforce.

Comment: @Grace yeah. I'm not saying you're not right, but to me, removing salutations is something you do when you *happen* to encounter them. I don't understand people who go actively *hunting* for them. Anyway, as you say, it's covered by the rules

Comment: @Pekka I think we're actually on the same page, but we express our distaste for the user's actions differently even though it may also be on the same page.

Comment: Grace yeah, I see now! :)

Comment: I did see that under the rules section. I suppose I read it differently than you (and others). Their logic behind not using a tagline is that your profile already provides unique information about yourself, therefore a unique tagline is pointless. However, simply saying "thanks" at the end of one post is more of a kind gesture rather than a tagline, thus it wouldn't fall into the "no taglines" rule. I'm not saying that you're wrong and I'm right, I'm just laying out my logic. I personally think edits should be used for making changes that contribute to the question, but he's within his rights

Comment: @Eclyps I would suggest you read the Meta discussion I linked. It goes into clearer detail as it is more explicit about greetings and salutations.

Comment: @Grace Thanks, I missed that in your first post - taking a look at it now. This is a very minor thing which I'm not too concerned about. I just wanted to make sure there he wasn't gaming the system.

Comment: For the record, we have some tools (dev-only) we can use for bulk signature removal